# SocketException Handling

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I can`t understand something simple. I have a class that handles the socket input. I have a catch-clause:

```
    public class EntryPoint implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket = null;
        private BufferedReader br = null; // receives data from the destination

...

        public void run() {     
            String command = null;      // buffer for holding one request from command line
            StringReader commandReader = null; // stream for reading command
            try {
                while (!socket.isClosed() && (command = br.readLine()) != null) {               
                    try {
                        command = command.trim();
                        commandReader = new StringReader(command);
                        Request req = JAXB.unmarshal(commandReader, Request.class); 
                        commandReader.close();  
                        dispatcher.sendRequest(req);                                        
                    } catch(DataBindingException ex) {
                        response.sendResponse(SystemMessageFactory.INVALID);
                        response.sendResponse(SystemMessageFactory.SOCKET_SHUTDOWN);
                    }                       
                }
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                System.out.println("Socket Exception");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Logger.getLogger("server").log(Level.SEVERE, 
                        "Error reading the command input of the client!", e);
            } 
        }       

    }
```

When the peer abruptly shuts down the socket, the connection reset is sent. The stack trace is:

```
16.07.2013 1:39:51 EntryPoint run
SEVERE: Error reading the command input of the client!
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:136)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:299)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:362)
    at blood.steel.server.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:36)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

How is it possible? I am catching it twice! SocketException is caught in its own catch-clause and in IOException catch clause. But nothing happens! It does not catch the socket exception. How can I handle it and what is the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: It's doing you a favor. Printing a fixed literal isn't adequate as a means of logging exceptions. Log the actual exception, not just some message of your own. And the isClosed() test is pointless. readLine() returning null is the correct test. You should close the socket and break on catching any IOException other than SocketTimeoutException, and maybe then too, depending on your requirements.

Comment: The Stack trace is there. It should not even appear, should it?

Comment: I am commenting, not answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the SocketExceptioon is not the one in `java.net.` Check your imports.

Or you are not running the code you think you are.

Comment: java.net.* - I just checked. How can I run the other code if I am starting it in Eclipse as a whole application? The InputStream of the Socket is read only from this class.

Comment: OMG, thanks. It was quite silly. I changed it and forgot to stop the process =) Nevertheless, Why isn`t it caught by the IOException clause? It is caught only when I explicitly state the SocketException-clause.

Comment: As you weren't running that code you can't expect *any* of it to execute.

Comment: Yep. Now it runs. Thanks guys. Stupid mistake =)